# Gregorian Calendar

Tags: java, calendar

I need to write an application that uses the GregorianCalendar and will print out the following items:
1. My date of birth
2. When I will be 1 billion seconds old

What I have so far:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class GregorianCalendar {

public static void main(String[] args){
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(); // Today's date
GregorianCalendar evansBirthday = new GregorianCalendar(1986,Calendar.November, 25);

System.out.println(evansBirthday);

//evansBirthday.add(Calendar.OCTOBER, 11574);
evansBirthday.

System.out.println(cal.add(Calendar.OCTOBER, 11574));

}
```

I am getting errors can you assist in helping me find them?

Comment: Seems like homework...

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the exact output you need.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class GregorianCalendar {

    public static void main(String[] args){
    GregorianCalendar evansBirthday = new GregorianCalendar(1986,Calendar.NOVEMBER, 25);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyy");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(evansBirthday.getTime()));
    evansBirthday.add(evansBirthday.SECOND, 1000000000);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(evansBirthday.getTime()));
    }
}
```

Output will be the following

```
11/25/1986
08/03/2018
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I copy pasted the code I still get the following errors. The import java.util.GregorianCalendar conflicts with a type defined in the same file 10:54 PM The constructor GregorianCalendar(int, int, int) is undefined The method add(int, int) is undefined for the type GregorianCalendar The method add(int, int) is undefined for the type GregorianCalenda

Comment: You have to erase everything in your file except the package at the very top.  The is complete file minus package name.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
GregorianCalendar evansBirthday = new GregorianCalendar(1986,Calendar.November, 25);    
System.out.println(evansBirthday);
evansBirthday.add(1000000000000); // A billion seconds
System.out.println(evansBirthday);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should copy and past the errors....

But for starters...

1. Calendar.November change to `Calendar.NOBEMBER`
2. You can not print `System.out.println(evansBirthday)` this will print some long GregorianCalendar java cod.  so you must convert it to Date object in the java.util.Calendar.

so add this, this will allow you to print out the dats

```
 Date newEvansBirthday = evansBirthday.getTime();

 System.out.println(newEvansBirthday);
```

1. adding time `evansBirthday.add(evansBirthday.SECOND, 1000000000);`

Comment: The import java.util.GregorianCalendar conflicts with a type defined in the same file  10:54 PM
The constructor GregorianCalendar(int, int, int) is undefined 
The method add(int, int) is undefined for the type GregorianCalendar 
The method add(int, int) is undefined for the type GregorianCalenda

Comment: why would you do all that work when you can add 1 billion seconds in 1 line? `evansBirthday.add(evansBirthday.SECOND, 1000000000);`

Comment: If you really need to print out a Calendar, you can always use `String.format("%tc", cal)` to get something human readable.